# Angular Unique Value in form

Tags: angular, forms, validation, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my form value of LicenseNumber has to be unique, so I wrote below validation:

```
     constructor(private doctorsService: DoctorsService,
              private location: Location,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
                this.rForm = this.fb.group({                     
              licenseNumber : ['', this.ControlLicenseNumber.bind(this)]});
                 }


                 ControlLicenseNumber(c: AbstractControl){
                  const value = c.get('licenseNumber').value;
                  return Object.keys(value).find(licenseNumber => c ===
                  value)  || null;
                }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.doctorsService.getDoctors().then(doctors => this.doctors = doctors);
  }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting error

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>       at AddDoctorComponent.ControlLicenseNumber

Maybe you know how properly bind this to my validator... Or where I am making mistake.

Greetings, Bartek

Comment: move the declaration of your form to ngInit and attach the validator once the value to your form is added

Comment: You mean that I should use NgOnChanges? Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

The validatior is given the licenseNumber Control, so you don't need to call `get('licenseNumber')`, just grab the value directly.

You also don't even need to bind the `ControlLicenseNumber` since you're not using `this` keyword within the method. But if you find yourself using `this` inside `ControlLicenseNumber()`, then keep the `bind`.

```
constructor(
  private doctorsService: DoctorsService,
  private location: Location,
  private fb: FormBuilder
) {
  this.rForm = this.fb.group({                     
    licenseNumber : ['', this.ControlLicenseNumber]
  });
}

ControlLicenseNumber(c: AbstractControl){

  // just get value
  const value = c.value;

  return Object.keys(value).find(licenseNumber => c ===
    value)  || null;
  }
}
```

That should fix the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` you mentioned.

I think your ControlLicenseNumber needs to return a function, too. Not just the result of the validation check: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators